# jquery ui datepicker format does not change

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

In my web site, I have two date inputs,

```
 <label>From : </label><input class="datepicker" id="from" name="from" value="<?php echo $from;?>" size=11 type="text">
 <label>To : </label><input class="datepicker" id="to" name="to" value="<?php echo $to ;?>" size=11 type="text">
```

And in the javascript part, I have the following code

```
$(function() {
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({ altFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
  //getter
  var altFormat = $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat" );
  //setter
  $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "altFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
  });
```

But when I select the date, it still returns a date with 04/04/2012 format instead of yy-mm-dd.

How should I solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, here we go again. first of all:

- **altFormat**: `The dateFormat to be used for the altField option. This allows one date format to be shown to the user for selection purposes, while a different format is actually sent behind the scenes. For a full list of the possible formats see the formatDate function`
- **dateFormat**: `The format for parsed and displayed dates. This attribute is one of the regionalisation attributes. For a full list of the possible formats see the`[formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate)`function.`

See Working [*jsFiddle Here*](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/ZayWQ/)

You might also want to see an answer i gave a [few minutes ago here, with more fiddles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10079112/jquery-ui-datepicker-format-does-not-change/10079329#10079329).